# Jenkins dsl pipeline def variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, workflow, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I'm trying to define a variable into a jenkins pipeline dsl script by reading 3 files and concatenating the output. The 3 files content is:

> file1 content is: 127
>
> file2 content is: 0
>
> file3 content is: 1

```
def var1 = readfile('file1')
def var2 = readfile('file2')
def var3 = readfile('file3')

def concatVar = "${var1} + '_' + ${var2} + '_' + ${var3}"
printin ${concatVar}
```

The output I expect would be

```
printIn${concatVar} 
127_0_1
```

instead my output is:

```
printIn ${concatVar} 
127
_0
_1
```

I know that I am wrong somewhere, but I don't know how to do it. Is there any of you familiar with the Jenkins pipepile dsl/groovy syntax?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this..

```
def var1 = readfile('file1').trim()
def var2 = readfile('file2').trim()
def var3 = readfile('file3').trim()

def concatVar = "${var1} + '_' + ${var2} + '_' + ${var3}"
println ${concatVar}
```

I found that readFile does not clip off the end of line character